# How to display a value from a array index in interval

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uafaLstf/1/

I have the following:

```
$(".span1").html("Warm Welcome To: " + "<br />");
arr = [];

arr.push(["john", "jdoe", "very nice"]);
arr.push(["mike", "mdone", "job well"]);
arr.push(["haan", "hgore", "creative"]);

var interval = 1000;
for (var f = 0; f < arr.length; f++) {
    SendWishes(arr[f][0]);
}

function SendWishes(name) {
    setTimeout(function () { $(".span1").html($(".span1").html() + name + "<br />"); }, 1000);
}

<span class="span1"></span>
```

What I am trying to do is display the name after every 1 second... however in my code the entire list is displayed without delay for each entry.

I think I am pretty close and missing something. Can someone please help with my code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is pass the value of `f` in the function and then use it to calculate the delay of setTimeout

```js
$(".span1").html("Warm Welcome To: " + "<br />");
arr = [];

arr.push(["john", "jdoe", "very nice"]);
arr.push(["mike", "mdone", "job well"]);
arr.push(["haan", "hgore", "creative"]);

var interval = 1000;
for (var f = 0; f < arr.length; f++) {
  SendWishes(arr[f][0], f);
}

function SendWishes(name, f) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(".span1").html($(".span1").html() + name + "<br />");
    if (f === arr.length - 1)
      console.log("Loop is over");
  }, 1000 * f);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="span1"></span>
```

Comment: Perfect... I had a feeling i was close. Thank you.

Comment: @11 minutes. :)

Comment: Why the downvotes here? Care to explain?

Comment: I +1 your answer I am not sure who downvoted.

Comment: @void Not sure, but I guess since it has a for-loop that it doesn't really need.

Comment: @nicael yea I saw your answer, I guess the for loop implementation is easier to read, also without an hardcoded 3. I dont see any reason not to use for loop here..

Comment: @void btw, not necessary to hard-core 3 either, one can just check `if(f<arr.length)`...

Comment: @void A side question, is there any way to see when the array loop is complete, I would like to show an alert that it's done. Thanks

Comment: @Si8 yes you can use `if (f === arr.length - 1)` condition. See the updated answer.

Comment: It displays the alert before the last entry is displayed... thanks

Comment: @Si8 that is because alert stops the execution of all the other statements. Instead try console.log() see the updated answer.

Comment: Yes i saw that. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need a for-loop at all. Just fire the `setTimeout` three times (or fire `setInterval` and reset it after 3 times).

Side notes:

1) optimisation: no need to call `arr.push` three times, you could do that in one call

2) you can use `$(".span1").append()` to shorten the code.

```
$(".span1").html("Warm Welcome To: " + "<br />");
arr = [];

arr.push(["john", "jdoe", "very nice"],
         ["mike", "mdone", "job well"],
         ["haan", "hgore", "creative"]);

var f = 0;

SendWishes();

function SendWishes() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $(".span1").append(arr[f++][0] + "<br />"); 
        if(f < 3) SendWishes();
        //OR: if(f < arr.length) in case you plan to push something else to your array
  }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Thank you @niacael... just realized that.